Azure alerting Creation using Python SDK
We are creating Azure alert using python SDK for Custom KQL query and below is the code which we are trying
from azure.mgmt.monitor import MonitorManagementClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()
sub_id= "xxxx"
resource_group = "rgname"
client = MonitorManagementClient(credential=credentials,subscription_id=sub_id)

# Define the KQL query
kql_query = """
ServiceMonitor
| where Computer contains "xyz-host"
| where SvcName contains "linux-service"
| where SvcState != "Running"
"""

# Create a unique name for the metric alert
metric_alert_name = "KQL_Metric_alert"

# Create the alert based on the KQL query
Alert = client.metric_alerts.create_or_update(resource_group,
        metric_alert_name,  # Use the unique metric alert name
        {
          "location": "global",
          "description": "Alert triggered when the service is not running on xyz_host",
          "severity": "3",
          "enabled": True,
          "scopes": [
            f"/subscriptions/{sub_id}/resourceGroups/{resource_group}"
          ],
          "evaluation_frequency": "PT1M",
          "window_size": "PT15M",
          "target_resource_type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
          "target_resource_region": "global",
          "criteria": {
            "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor.MultipleResourceMultipleMetricCriteria",
            "all_of": [
              {
                "criterion_type": "StaticThresholdCriterion",
                "metric_name": "KQLQueryExecutionResult",
                "metric_namespace": "",
                "operator": "GreaterThan",
                "threshold": 0,
                "aggregation": "Count",
                "dimensions": [],
                "metric_namespace": "microsoft.insights/components",
                "additional_properties": {
                  "query": kql_query
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "auto_mitigate": False,
          "actions": [
              {
                  "action_group_id": f"/subscriptions/{sub_id}/resourceGroups/rg-name/providers/microsoft.insights/actionGroups/AlertTrigger",
                  "webhook_properties": {}
              }
          ]
        }
    )

print("Alert created Successfully.")

We get below error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/testuser/Documents/test/alerting/service_check.py", line 21, in <module>
    Alert = client.metric_alerts.create_or_update(resource_group,
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/vcimalap/Documents/test/alerting/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/azure/core/tracing/decorator.py", line 78, in wrapper_use_tracer
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/vcimalap/Documents/test/alerting/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/azure/mgmt/monitor/v2018_03_01/operations/_metric_alerts_operations.py", line 609, in create_or_update
    raise HttpResponseError(response=response, model=error, error_format=ARMErrorFormat)
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: (BadRequest) Required property 'name' not found in JSON. Path '', line 1, position 512. Activity ID: df779cd2-198b-4098-be4f-c68d95c27f00.
Code: BadRequest
Message: Required property 'name' not found in JSON. Path '', line 1, position 512. Activity ID: df779cd2-198b-4098-be4f-c68d95c27f00.

We are not sure whats the wrong with code and anybody fixing issue will be great
Python version: 3.11
package versions:
azure-common==1.1.28
azure-core==1.30.1
azure-identity==1.16.0
azure-mgmt-core==1.4.0
azure-mgmt-monitor==6.0.2
certifi==2024.2.2
cffi==1.16.0
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
cryptography==42.0.5
idna==3.7
isodate==0.6.1
msal==1.28.0
msal-extensions==1.1.0
packaging==24.0
portalocker==2.8.2
pycparser==2.22
PyJWT==2.8.0
requests==2.31.0
six==1.16.0
typing_extensions==4.11.0
urllib3==2.2.1


Based on the error message shared it looks like the request body not having mandatory parameter "name" in file "_metric_alerts_operations.py". Also try to add "name" attribute inside metric_alert_name block, this should help.

I tried i :)  but no luck

can you please update metric_alert_name dynamically. Like postfix with some integer or random number generated from random package.
